# What use are sensors to an explorer?

Tags: elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-odyssey

I'm in the process of outfitting my first proper exploration ship. I plan to fly into the deep black and spend several days/weeks there. My goal is to take my time and enjoy the process - fully scan every system, detailed-scan every notable planetary body, fly to the surface and land most of the time.

I'm working out the exact specs of my ship and I got stuck at sensors. As far as I understand, sensors are no longer that useful as they were a couple years back thanks to Full Spectrum Scanner. Flying over the surface, looking for signal sources is also not needed thanks to the Detailed Surface Scanner.

**Is there any reason for explorers, to pack any other Sensors grade than D?** I'd rather figure this out now than when I'm thousands of Ly out of the bubble. Thanks and o7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for an explorer build, you want the lightest (D) sensors, and may want to do “lightweight” engineering on them.

I guess it’s possible for a build to be lightest with the lowest power (E) sensors to get a lighter power plant, but power draw of E and D sensors is low enough that’s unlikely to work out.

Sensors mostly only apply to “normal” space, not supercruise.

Engineering for wider scan angle might also work in supercruise, but I doubt that’s of any use for an explorer.

Higher rated scanners are handy for bounty hunting in rings, and stuff like that, but otherwise explorers, combat ships, traders, etc all usually want the lightest (D) scanners.